# what is the meaning of google_experiment_mod in chrome localstorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I am storing some items in chrome local storage. Along with my variables I can see

> google_experiment_mod: "335"

I am wondering what it means.

Below is the code to to store the items and I use chrome developer tool to see the content.

```
localStorage.setItem("freqInMins", response.freqInMins);
```

Thanks

Comment: probably you are using a nightly build of Chrome, and may be they are using this `google_experiment_mod: "335"`

Answer (score 4):

google_experiment_mod is used by Google AdSense for experimenting with which advertisement perform best on a website. Please refer to [“How Google uses data when you use our partners’ sites”.](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/partners/)

Answer (score 1):

I have that too under the web inspector, but only on certain sites. I use mac and I am using Safari. I also found while searching "experiments" in the resource content on the google homepage something that says "dnssec-nd.gexperiments1.com", so I'm guessing that "gexperiments" means "googleexperiments" , and its probably something google uses to track everyone's time or something like that. so its probably nothing.